# How to find Bottleneck features without using ImageDataGenerator class

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset of Images and it has many classes. I have my training images in a SINGLE directory. My idea is to use bottleneck features of VGG16/Inception model which are pre-trained on Imagenet dataset. I was going through [Keras Document](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) and other related blogs and figured out that my training images should be in separate sub-folders according to different classes if I have to use ImageDataGenerator class and fit_generator of Keras. Rather than creating sub-folders of different classes and putting related images inside it, I want to write my own function to read images.

Is there any other way (without using ImageDataGenerator) class by which I can create bottleneck features and then train small Fully connected layers on it? Any theoretical guidelines would be helpful.

Basically, I am implementing different techniques/models like kNN, two layer Neural Net, CNN (LeNet, AlexNet etc.) and now fine-tuning on big models like (VGG, Inception, ResNet etc) on same dataset to compare the accuracy and learning. I might be completely wrong in my thinking to perform above steps. So any clarification or path regarding this would be great.

Comment: Of course you can load images in any way you want, but your question is not really specific, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Okay. This is what I am doing.
1. I deleted few class images from my dataset to make my problem simple and now I have 2 classes each with 12500 images
2. Read images with opencv and store them in numpy array
2. Store labels accordingly.
3. Generate train/validation data randomly.
4. Create VGG16 with include_top = False using Keras
5. Finding bottleneck features. Storing them in .npy and then loading them
6. Training model on a simple network(2 Dense,1 dropout, output) layer
Output for now : My validation accuracy is fluctuating and and validation loss is increasing.
Thank you.